# angular 6 custom elements fail on IE11 and Firefox with syntax and shadow dom errors

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

I have created a new angular-cli project, with a custom element using [these directions](https://medium.com/@tomsu/building-web-components-with-angular-elements-746cd2a38d5b). It works perfectly on Chrome.
I have commented in all the necessary polyfills for Internet Explorer.

I have included the additional `@webcomponents/`... BUT `@webcomponents` is causing a problem!

`node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim.js`
contains an arrow function, that is not supported by internet explorer, so I am getting the following error:

> Syntax Error
>   If anyone can point me to an angular-cli demo / repo **(with custom elements)** anywhere that compiles and works on IE11 that would be a huge help!

[image]

[image]

```
 // `node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim.js`
 *  Compiling valid class-based custom elements to ES5 will satisfy these
 *  requirements with the latest version of popular transpilers.
 */
(() => { // THIS IS NOT ACTUALLY LEGAL IN IE
  'use strict';

  // Do nothing if `customElements` does not exist.
  if (!window.customElements) return;
```

My full polyfills looks like the below:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min';
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim';
import 'bluebird';

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Comment: I didn't think firefox implements shadow dom (apparently you can turn it on with a preference though) - can you please be clear which errors are in which browser - as firefox definitely supports arrow functions ... please show the error message, not just some vague description of it

Comment: Is your target inside your tsconfig.json set to es5?

Comment: @PierreDuc, yes

Comment: I'm currently working on the same topic. I used another approach for bootstrapping which - for now - is also not working, but maybe it gives you some input that may solve the issue: https://github.com/robertfoobar/ng6-ce-consumer

Comment: Even with no ViewEncapsulation.Native, I cannot get this to work. I only have encapsulation modes None and the default Emulated set in my Angular Element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/sulco/angular-6-web-components/pull/2

Here man, this saved my sanity in the last 2 days, click and be blessed ;D

Basically the guy removed Native encapsulation from the component and used polyfills in apparently correct manner, which I was unable to establish myself.

If you checkout this pull request, run `npm install`, `npm run build`, `npm run package` and `npm run serve`, all should work on Chrome, FF and IE11 (works for me at least).

Answer (score 2):

The proposed answer won't work in all of the cases, according to my experience. Just try to place 2 angular based web components in one file and you will not get the expected behavior. Checkout this [artice](https://medium.com/@neckster/how-to-build-real-web-components-with-angular-6-ac842c9062dd) for an up to date working example.

Comment: agreed: we've abandoned this... it just doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Actually it works in IE, if you don't use shadow div (ViewEncapsualtion.Native). But from my point of view, shadow div is important feature, which makes web components really useful.